# Проблема при парсинге файла

Tags: python, парсер

Использую Python 2.6.1 на ОС Linux Ubuntu. Выполнял считывание данных из файла, и потом создавал словарик. Раньше все было ок. На данный момент решил использовать тот же скрипт для считывания. Вот его функция -  парсер данных из файла:

```
f_conf = open(module_path() + 'config.ini', 'r') 
d_conf = {}
invalid_lines = "\n"
for line in f_conf.readlines():
    try:
        if line == '\n':
            continue
        d_conf[line.split('=')[0].replace(' ','')] = line.split('=')[1].replace(' ', '').replace('\n', '')
    except:
        invalid_lines += line.rstrip('\n') + '\n'
```

При этом я убираю пробелы и символы перевода строки. Раньше, в частности на Windows, все хорошо работало, а на Linux перестал отлавливать символ перевода строки '\n'. Долго искал, а как оказалось, проблема элементарна: код перевода строки, как известно, равен  13, а код `ord('\n') = 10`. Проблема в принципе решена, но остается вопрос, как тогда раньше работал скрипт, и как возможно еще перехватить или заменить символ перевода, кроме варианта `.replace(chr(13), '')` ?

Comment: "код перевода строки, как известно, равен 13" - это откуда. 13 - код возврата каретки (CR). И, вообще, с текстовыми файлами поаккуратнее - разделители зависят от операционной системы. См. описание функции open и метода readlines (какие там ещё '\n' ?)

Comment: Спасибо за полноценные ответы. Кстати насчет изобретателя велосипедов, не было времени искать, а с моим умением задавать вопросы гуглу, поэтому решил по-быстрому смастерить скрипт сам. Теперь буду точно использовать ConfigParser

Answer (score 4):

> код перевода строки, как известно, равен 13

Вы заблуждаетесь. Код 13 имеет символ \r (carriage return, CR), а код 10 имеет символ \n (line feed, LF). [Перевод строки-же](http://ru.wikipedia.org/wiki/%D0%9F%D0%B5%D1%80%D0%B5%D0%B2%D0%BE%D0%B4_%D1%81%D1%82%D1%80%D0%BE%D0%BA%D0%B8) зависит от платформы. Для *nix - это символ \n, а для Windows - это последовательность символов \r\n.

> но остается вопрос, как тогда раньше работал скрипт

Вероятно, раньше вы редактировали этот файл в *nix и символ перевода строки в файле был \n, а затем вы отредактировали его в Windows и, соответственно, к символу \n добавился \r

> и как возможно еще перехватить или заменить символ перевода

В питоне есть специальный [режим чтения файла 'U'](http://docs.python.org/library/functions.html#open), при котором все платформозависимые символы перевода строк транслируются в \n

И как правильно вам уже ответили выше, для парсинга конфига уже существует готовое решение в виде класса ConfigParser

Answer (score 2):

Посмотрел, очумел, офигел и вот ... идите вот смотрите: [ConfigParser](http://docs.python.org/library/configparser.html#module-ConfigParser)

То что доктор прописал от страшной болезни изобретателя велосипедов? ;-)
И еще, загоните вот это в интерпретатор:

```
  >> "  asdfg  ".strip()
```